# Frame problems with video recorded using Camtasia

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video, mouse

I'm using Blender only as a video editor. I've recorded several screen captures using Camtasia with 25 fps. They are encoded as AVI files with the video codec "TechSmith Camtasia Screen Capture (tscc)" and the audio codec "PCM S16 LE (araw)". All of them play fine using VLC.

The videos contain a Power Point presentation with a moving mouse cursor and me talking during the presentation as the audio.

Now the problem is: When I use these videos in Blender it looks like that the frame order is messed up. By this I mean that the mouse arrow in the video is not moving smoothly like it does when playing the video in VLC but instead is jumping around all the time.

I tried to fix the problem using a "Speed Control" effect strip but that doesn't help.

Has anybody experienced something similar or has any idea how this could be solved?

Thank you.

Comment: My guess is that the video is recorded with a variable frame rate(vfr), and Blender needs a constant frame rate(cfr). For this file to work properly in Blender you'll need to convert it with a gui for ffmpeg like Handbrake before you import it in Blender.

Comment: @tintwotin according [this Camtasia support page](https://support.techsmith.com/hc/en-us/articles/360040788091-Camtasia-Target-Capture-Frame-Rate) you are right. I tried it and it solved the problem. If you care to post it as an answer I can accept it.